# How can I convert 3ds model to osgjs format?

Tags: 3d, webgl, 3dsmax, openscenegraph, osg.js

I have scan of territory in Photoscan Professional 1.0.4. 
I can export this scan to .3ds format. 
But i need to render this model in browser via WebGL with OSG.js library.

How can i convert .3ds model to osgjs format?

Comment: Is it LIDAR terrain data and are you committed to OSGJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an OSG (not OSGJS) native code plugin that can export to the osgjs format. OSG itself can load 3DS format. So you can use the osgconv tool to convert your 3DS model to osgjs.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/osgjs/3KvHPpKXvWQ

However, if you're doing LIDAR scanned terrain, OSGJS may not (by itself) be the best tool for the job. There are more specialized LIDAR display tools, which can run in WebGL.